# Reading already-written text from console

Tags: java, console

I feel silly asking this but: how can I read a string from a console **that is not input but has already been written to the console**?

For instance, if I print a line to the console how can I read it after the fact? I know this is atypical.

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way.  Keep a copy before you output, if you need it.

Comment: Agreed. I'm testing a program.

Comment: Redirect standard output to go to a file.

Comment: Can you redirect the output to a file rather than attempt to read it from the console?

Answer (score 2):

Except in certain special circumstances, you can't, as Brad pointed out in the comments. As a justification, consider that when you send some text to the console (via standard output or standard error) to be printed, there's no guarantee that the text actually will be printed. Perhaps the user has redirected that output stream to `/dev/null`, in which case the text is gone for good. Or perhaps the text has scrolled out of view.

Basically, don't count on ever being able to access something that was sent to the console for output. If you need it, keep a copy in your program. And if you're trying to get at something that *another* program sent to the console, you need to use some sort of different arrangement like shared memory, sockets, or a fifo pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Replace both System.in and System.out with your own streams and
try to create a pipe between System.in and System.out;

I am not sure that, whether it works or not;